# How can I intercept all network calls coming out of my C app?

Tags: networking, intercept

I'm working on a large, legacy project and for some complicated reasons, I want to see all the network requests coming out. I tried hooking `socket(1)`, but it doesn't seem to catch everything. I'm doing this for Apple devices (UNIX-y, with both BSD and POSIX calls).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to see all the network requests coming out.

I would use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) for that.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if `strace` could be of use to you. It will print to the console all system calls as they are made by a given program. In this case, it can be used to filter socket related system calls.

```
strace -e socket,connect,send,etc... /your/program
```